# Get a random record from table where a field is null

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, sql-update

I am trying to retrieve a random apartment from the database table where the ownerID is `null`. This script is used for a GTA 5 Server on AltV the problem is the `letrandomHouse = Math.floor(Math.random()*res.length);` it wont update the Apartment's owner where id is

```
player.data.ownerID = res[0]["id"];
            con.query('SELECT * FROM apartements WHERE owner = null', function(err, res, row){
                if(res){
                    let randomHouse = Math.floor(Math.random()*res.length);
                    console.log(randomHouse);
                    con.query('UPDATE apartements SET owner = ? WHERE id = ?', [player.data.ownerID, randomHouse], function(res, err, row){
                        if (err){
                            console.log(err);
                            console.log("test");
                        }
                        console.log(res);
                    });
                    console.log(res);
                } else {
                    console.log(err);
                }
});
```

Full Export Function

```
export function registerHouse(player){
    con.query('SELECT `id` FROM characters WHERE accountID = ?', [player.data.accountID], function(err, res, row){
        if(!err){
            player.data.ownerID = res[0]["id"];
            con.query('SELECT * FROM apartements WHERE owner = null', function(err, res, row){
                if(res){
                    let randomHouse = Math.floor(Math.random()*res.length);
                    console.log(randomHouse);
                    con.query('UPDATE apartements SET owner = ? WHERE id = ?', [player.data.ownerID, randomHouse], function(res, err, row){
                        if (err){
                            console.log(err);
                            console.log("test");
                        }
                        console.log(res);
                    });
                    console.log(res);
                } else {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            });
        } else {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A problem with your code is the `WHERE` clause in the `SELECT` statement:

```
WHERE owner = null
```

This will never match. To check for nullness, you need the `IS NULL` construct.

But as far as concerns, you can do what you want with a single statement:

```
update apartements 
set owner = ? 
where owner is null
order by rand()
limit 1
```

Comment: so thats means i would not need to first select all am i right? and the order by rand() limit 1 would update like one of 20 apartements?

Comment: @MisterLA: yes, exactly.